# Release and Debug build in the same Service Client app

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, service, client-server

I have a Console app which has a service reference to a staging service. After testing I want to deploye the Console app to my Live environment. But here the Console app has to reference a different Production service (which has a different wsdl file and endpoint)

I have also added both service reference to the same project and Rebuild the Solution once in Debug mode and next in Release mode in Visual Studio. But when running the program in 'Release' mode it still refers to the staging class references.

Is there any way of solving this problem. 
Thanks.

Comment: Not sure there is a good solution for this.  In my opinion the service you are debugging against should be same as what is in release. Only change is the url

Comment: The only other way I am getting around is creating a copy of my program and changing the Service reference from Staging to Production. Rebuild it and then deploy to Live. I was hoping I wont have to maintain two applications, so the question.